# Unable to remove Share Extension from project ,it still appear in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile-safari, ios-app-extension

I am testing to integrate share extension to my existing app. By adding it via File>New>Target>Share Extensions

But when I removed it whether by reset my git to previous commit or delete it from project. The share extension option still appear in Safari.   Even if I tried with a complete new device .It still appear there. So this is getting ridiculous now because when I create new share extension .The share button in Safari just displays my app sharing feature in double.

Anyone know how to solve this problem ?  TIA

Comment: found a solution "Clean your project (cmd + shift + k) then run again"

Comment: If that works, you should answer your question and then accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution
 "Clean your project (cmd + shift + k) then run again"